# Combine specific rows of a dataframe and delete unused rows

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df1 which looks like this:

```
details            endFrame id  indexID object  startFrame
'series of numbers’  1111   78  0   Motorbike   1
'series of numbers’  3647   78  1   Motorbike   1112
'series of numbers’  3678   78  2   Motorbike   3649
'series of numbers’  704    120 3   Pedestrian  66
'series of numbers’  817    120 4   Pedestrian  705
'series of numbers’  922    120 5   Pedestrian  818
'series of numbers’  121    110 6   Pedestrian  69
'series of numbers’  140    109 7   Pedestrian  69
'series of numbers’  4161   109 8   Pedestrian  140
'series of numbers’  4344   109 9   Pedestrian  4163
'series of numbers’  3603   79  10  Motorbike   70
```

And I have another df2 that looks like this:

```
indexID matchID
0   1
1   2
3   4
4   5
7   8
8   9
```

The match ID shows which IDs that need to be joined. For example, from the first 2 rows indexs 0,1 and 2 should be joined together. In df1, all the details should be just added together. The final final df should look like this:

```
details                                                       id    indexID
'series of numbers’'series of numbers’'series of numbers’     78    0
'series of numbers’'series of numbers’'series of numbers’     120   3
'series of numbers’                                           110   6
'series of numbers’'series of numbers’'series of numbers’     109   7
'series of numbers’                                            79   10
```

How do I do this?

**EDIT**
The series of numbers is actually a list so instead of having an output like this:

```
details                                                  id    indexID
[series of numbers][series of numbers][series of numbers]     78    0
[series of numbers][series of numbers][series of numbers]     120   3
[series of numbers]                                           110   6
[series of numbers][series of numbers][series of numbers]     109   7
[series of numbers]                                            79   10
```

I would like it to have an output like this:

```
details                                                  id    indexID
[series of numbersseries of numbersseries of numbers]     78    0
[series of numbersseries of numbersseries of numbers]     120   3
[series of numbers]                                           110   6
[series of numbersseries of numbersseries of numbers]     109   7
[series of numbers]                                            79   10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace matched values to missing values by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and forward fill by previous values:

```
g = df1['indexID'] .mask(df1['indexID'].isin(df2['matchID'])).ffill().astype(int)
print (g)
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      3
4      3
5      3
6      6
7      7
8      7
9      7
10    10
Name: indexID, dtype: int32
```

Then use `groupby` with `join`:

```
#if want grouping only be new Series g
df = df1.groupby(g).agg({'details':' '.join, 'id':'first'}).reset_index()
print (df)
   indexID                                            details   id
0        0  'series of numbers' 'series of numbers' 'serie...   78
1        3  'series of numbers' 'series of numbers' 'serie...  120
2        6                                'series of numbers'  110
3        7  'series of numbers' 'series of numbers' 'serie...  109
4       10                                'series of numbers'   79
```

---

```
#or also by id column
df = df1.groupby(['id',g], sort=False)['details'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()
print (df)
    id  indexID                                            details
0   78        0  'series of numbers' 'series of numbers' 'serie...
1  120        3  'series of numbers' 'series of numbers' 'serie...
2  110        6                                'series of numbers'
3  109        7  'series of numbers' 'series of numbers' 'serie...
4   79       10                                'series of numbers'
```

Comment: Actually, we can get the desired output directly using `df.groupby('id').agg({'details':' '.join,'indexID':'first'}).reset_index()` without using `df2` but not sure why OP wants to use df2.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - I think OP want use `df2` in my opinion.

Comment: @jezrael I forgot one detail. The 'series of numbers' is actually a list. So after joining the data together, the information in the details column becomes a few lists put together. How can I make it into one list?

Comment: @RuvenGuna - Do you use first or second solution?

Comment: @RuvenGuna - You need `df = df1.groupby(['id',g], sort=False)['details'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael Yes i did use the second one. I tried your code and it still does not return one long list. I have edited my question to reflect what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - I think I understand, need `df = df1.groupby(['id',g], sort=False)['details'].agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()`

Comment: ValueError: Function does not reduce

Comment: @RuvenGuna - maybe pandas version problem, what about `df = df1.groupby(['id',g], sort=False)['details'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that makes each list into a a string and it just appends them together, seperated by a comma. It becomes this ["[]","[]","[]"]

Comment: @RuvenGuna - OK, what is `print (type(df1.loc[0, 'details']))` of input DataFrame?

Comment: String. It's okay. I can work with it being a few lists joined together. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id'])
       .groupby('id', sort=False).details
       .apply(''.join)
```